# DB Design: Table Inheritance and Hierarchy

Tags: oracle, inheritance, database-design, hierarchy

The example used does not represent the domain I am actually solving for; it's just for example.

**Background**

I am defining [table inheritance](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html). Planning to use Table API packages & views to handle the necessary logic & presentation.

I also need to define multiple multi-level named hierarchies with disparate attributes.

Combining table inheritance (Location > State, City) & named hierarchies (State <- City), however, is where I've come across a design snag.

**The Problem**

I want to define a Unique Key enforcing Name of City is Unique within State, but the abstraction of the Name field is preventing that. I can handle it in PL/SQL if needed, but I would like to enforce it at the SQL level (ideally without an additional table) if at all possible.

**Constraints**

Other tables need to be able to refer to any level of the hierarchy generically (location).

Other tables also need to be able to refer to a specific level of the hierarchy.

**Thoughts**

I cannot do [single table inheritance](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/singleTableInheritance.html) due to the complexity of the graph of relations.

I have thought about duplicating the Name field for ease, though I'd rather not violate Normal Forms.

**Example**

```
CREATE TABLE location
( id      NUMBER  (  38) PRIMARY KEY
, name    VARCHAR2(1000) NOT NULL
, type_id NUMBER  (  38) NOT NULL
--, other common/super attributes
);

CREATE TABLE state
( id NUMBER(38) PRIMARY KEY
                REFERENCES location (id)
--, child attributes
);

CREATE TABLE city
( id       NUMBER(38) PRIMARY KEY
                      REFERENCES location (id)
, state_id NUMBER(38) NOT NULL
                      REFERENCES state    (id)
--, child attributes
);
```

Comment: There are 6 Springfields in Wisconsin. Texarkana is in both Texas and Arkansas

Comment: States/Cities is not my actual problem domain; I'm just using it as an example, so the reality of duplicate city names is not a concern.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why requiring city and state names to be unique (and therefore holding them in the relevant table) would violate any normal form. city name is not the same attribute as state name "New York" city != "New York" state for example.

Comment: To Clarify: there can be 2 Cities named New York in different States, there can also be a State & a City each named New York, but there cannot be 2 Cities named New York in the same State.

Answer (score 0):

Adding a "parent_location" to location table maybe works for you.

```
CREATE TABLE location
( id      NUMBER  (  38) PRIMARY KEY
, name    VARCHAR2(1000) NOT NULL
, type_id NUMBER  (  38) NOT NULL
, parent_location_id number( 38) NOT NULL
--, other common/super attributes
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX location_u2
   ON location (parent_location_id, name);

CREATE TABLE city
( id       NUMBER(38) PRIMARY KEY
                      REFERENCES location (id)
, --state_id gone away
--, child attributes
);
```

It also would prevent having two states with the same name.

The disadvantage is you'll need to use a dummy "0" location_id for the top node.

Best regards.

Comment: While this does prevent duplicate states, it does not prevent duplicates cities within state. The solution should be applicable to any level of the hierarchy.

Comment: Hi Peter,

Let's say you have two states:
id name parent_location_id
1. Oregon      0
2. California   0

Now you enter a city:
3. Portland   1

You will not able to enter another city with name = "Portland" and parent_location_id = 1, as it would violate the unique constraint.

Comment: Agreed; that's why I need a "Unique Key enforcing Name of City is Unique within State" So state_id & name are both required. My question revolves around strategies to reorganize my tables to make it possible to define a unique constraint on those 2 fields.